# Mutate and recode function running very slowly

Tags: r, dplyr

Just wondering if anyone else is having a problem? I am recoding a variable using code as below:

```
CT_variables <- CT_variables %>%
  mutate(InjuryHx.InjType = recode(InjuryHx.InjType, "1" = "Closed",
"2" = "A",
"3" = "B",
"5" = "C",
"6" = "D",
"7" = "E",
"8" = "F",
"88" = "Unknown"))
```

It is only a few thousand variables and was working fine up until yesterday afternoon but is now taking 2 minutes to complete. I have tried removing and reloading packages, restarting computer, updating R studio etc but to no avail. I would normally expect my computer set up (as was yesterday) to complete this in <10 secs.

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced this and has a fix?

Comment: (1) `recode` is superseded in favor of `case_match()` (in dplyr-1.1.2, don't know offhand when it was superseded). (2) I find relatively-simple cases like this to be more directly written either as "dictionary" lookups or as left-joins. I suspect (without testing) that they would be faster in cases like this.

Comment: For instance, a simple "dictionary" lookup might be `vec <- c("1" = "Closed", "2" = "A", ...)` and then eventually `... %>% mutate(InjType = vec[InjType])`; if there's a chance of finding new values and you want to retain them, use instead `coalesce(vec[InjType], InjType)`; if there are unmatched values and you want them changed to a default static, then `coalesce(vec[InjType], "BadValue")` or similar.

Comment: What I really don't understand is how it can suddenly stop working with no changes made to the code...It is a bit frustrating! Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, I understand, that can be frustrating. I don't know that I can offer much advice without knowing (a lot) more about your data and system. For instance, did the size of the data grow significantly? Did you update any packages, even if not `dplyr`? Was there an OS update? What is the rest of the system load? ... the list could go on for a while ...